# Finding and using clojure.contrib.string

Tags: eclipse, string, clojure, clojure-contrib, counterclockwise

I have CounterClockwise for Eclipse and believe clojure.contrib should be installed. However, I can't seem to use it or any of the subfiles such as clojure.contrib.string. If I type as I get the following errors

If I type  (require 'clojure-contrib.string) I get:

FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure_contrib/string__init.class or clojure_contrib/string.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

Comment: http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

Comment: What makes you think clojure.contrib should be installed? who installed it? to where? Clojure deps are usually managed on a per project basis, automatically, and contrib is not compatible with up to date versions of Clojure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long ago in an internet far far away Clojure had a large utility library called clojure.contrib which turned out to be rather hard to maintain, so it was broken up into many libraries, each of which uses the [Clojure contributors agreement](http://clojure.org/contributing). In this process **clojure.contrib.string became just clojure.string** and the names of all the other projects changed and they are released independently now. Seeing references to clojure.contrib is a sign that **you are looking at outdated documentation**. Also watch out for tutorials that make references to installing Clojure or installing dependencies without [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/).

Comment: Whoa, it didn't become clojure.string - that existed long before c.c.string. When contrib disappeared, maybe a function or two were moved into clojure.string, but most of them just disappeared.

Comment: @amalloy My source is http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go end of the third paragraph reads: "clojure.contrib.string migrated to clojure.string".

Comment: Well, I guess that's what happened in the upgrade from clojure 1.1 to 1.2, so it's not incorrect; but usually the "where did contrib go" article is about upgrading from 1.2 to something newer, when contrib actually vanished as a whole.